# RESTful resource routing

Tags: php, api, rest, laravel

If I'm defining a REST route to create forms as such:

```
POST /form
GET /form/{id}
POST /form/{id}
```

If I want to define routes for form submissions now, would I do like this?

```
POST /form/{id}/submissions
```

or would it be a completely different resource like:

```
POST /formsubmission
```

Comment: It depends how you consider form submissions : is it a completely different entity or isn't it just a form with a specific property ? What is the different (for you) between a form and a form submission ?

Comment: would consider it a different entity, the form would hold values like which fields to display and other properties. The form submission would be values for those fields that are populated by a user.

Comment: the only action we would need for form submissions is storing, we wouldn't need to retrieve or update or delete, so that's why I don't think it'd make sense to have a completely separate controller for just that one action. Would it be ok to add another method to our FormController for just this action?

Answer (score 0):

If you are building a dynamic User Interface then ideally you should use a `GET` request to request the form elements. And with the help of a `PUT` or a `POST` request, you should submit the data.

```
GET /form/{id}
POST /form/{id}
```